# How to convert unmanaged C struct to C# to call LsaLogonUser

Tags: c#, authentication, winapi, struct

I'm trying to call LsaLogonUser to authenticate an user using his username/password pair (alternatives like LogonUser are not valid for this project). To do that, I'm trying to define the structure to store the user's information that I should pass to LsaLogonUser.

First of all, I need to define the MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON, which according to Microsoft it should be something like this:

```
typedef struct _MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON {
  MSV1_0_LOGON_SUBMIT_TYPE MessageType;
  UNICODE_STRING           LogonDomainName;
  UNICODE_STRING           UserName;
  UNICODE_STRING           Password;
} MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON
```

Looking at PInvoke, I find out that the [UNICODE_STRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/subauth/ns-subauth-unicode_string) struct is defined in C# as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct UNICODE_STRING : IDisposable
{
   public ushort Length;
   public ushort MaximumLength;
   private IntPtr buffer;

   public UNICODE_STRING(string s)
   {
     Length = (ushort)(s.Length * 2);
     MaximumLength = (ushort)(Length + 2);
     buffer = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(s);
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
     Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
     buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
   }

   public override string ToString()
   {
     return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(buffer);
   }
}
```

With this definition, It should be trivial to define the MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON struct. **However**, if we read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsalogonuser) for the LsaLogonUser function, it clearly specifies that "The LogonDomainName, UserName, and Password members of the MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON structure must point to buffers in memory that are **contiguous** to the structure itself". With this new piece of information, I guess that the final struct that I should pass to LsaLogonUser should be something like this :

```
struct {
    MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON auth;
    WCHAR dombuf[256];
    WCHAR usrbuf[256];
    WCHAR pwdbuf[256];
  } FINAL_STRUCT;
```

And in this scenario, the buffer field of each one of the UNICODE_STRING fields of the MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON struct should point to their corresponding buffer in the final struct (e.g. auth.LogonDomainName.buffer should point to dombuf and so on).

I don't know how to put all of this together. First, I guess i should change  the UNICODE_STRING struct definition, so the buffer field uses an unmanaged pointer. But then, I dont know either how to make it point to the contiguous buffers, or how to even define them in the final struct.

Comment: Removed `c` tag.

Comment: You seem to have all pieces together already. Where's your actual problem?

Comment: @PMF 1.- How do I define FINAL_STRUCT with unmanaged WCHAR buffers contiguous to the MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON  struct? 2.- How can I make it so the buffer field of the UNICODE_STRING contained in MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON  point to the contiguous buffers?

Comment: Some "dynamically-sized" structs are difficult to marshal between .NET and native, they can't be completely defined using simple definitions. You have an example here: https://www.stuartmathews.com/index.php/893-using-c-and-fast-connect-api

Comment: The UNICODE _LINK says that string ends with a NULL which is '\0'.

Comment: This should be available through [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32).

Comment: @IInspectable Didn't know about this project, and I have to say that it's pretty awesome. Despite that, I have imported the whole Windows.Win32.Security.Authentication.Identity namespace and the MSV1_0_LM20_LOGON structure (which is a key part of my question) is not defined.

Comment: If an API or type is missing you'll need to let the [Win32 Metadata](https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata) maintainers know.

Comment: As it turns out, the `MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON` definition is apparently part of the Win32 Metadata (see the [windows-rs documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Security/Authentication/Identity/struct.MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON.html), for example; another client of the metadata). You'd probably want to bring this to the attention of the C#/Win32 team then.